# Error while compling built in examples of QT

Tags: qt

I loaded an example from `QT`, `Qt Quick Extras - Dashboard program`.
When i run the code as it is, i get an error,

P.S... a complete novice to QT Quick

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>      QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders. shader compilation
>      failed: "Failed to create D3D shaders." QOpenGLShader::link: Failed
>      to create D3D shaders. Failed to create D3D shaders.
>      QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is
>      not linked QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
>      QSGMaterialShader: Shader compilation failed: "Failed to create D3D
>      shaders.\n" QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders. Failed
>      to create D3D shaders. QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix 
>      ): shader program is not linked
>      QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is 
>      not linked QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( pixelSize ): shader
>      program is not linked QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D
>      shaders. Failed to create D3D shaders.

---

Comment: Can you link the example so we can check where the error can come from ? But it just looks like you didn't link the OpenGL library or something like that

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? Sounds like https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44815

Comment: how do i link the openGL libraries ?

Comment: I am using QT 5.2.1